# How to create URL for Base58 encoded IDs

Tags: url, encoding

I am planning to use Base58 encoding for IDs in URL in a new project.

An URL might look like `example.com/sTPTi`.

I am concerned about the possibility that a generated URL might coincide with a statically routed section like `example.com/contacts`.

I have an idea that I could insert a slash after the first symbol in the generated URLs. Thus my example would look like this: `example.com/s/TPTi`. And I could avoid all the risks by not using a single-symbol static routes. Is that a sane solution?

I am aware that I could prefix the generated URLs with something static like the common `example.com/i/sTPTi` but my solution makes it shorter by 2 symbols. I am also aware that the generated URLs could be simply prefixed by a symbol that I'd need to avoid for static URLs like prefixing the generated ones by a 9: `example.com/9sTPTi` but that somehow seems a bit dumb.